# Animated sticky header that changes WITH scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make an animated sticky header like hundreds of other websites. The difference is that I'm wanting the animation to move with the scrolling rather than after passing a certain scroll point, snapping to the new size.

An example of what I'm trying to do is on this site: http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/

Any help appreciated, I'm very new to javascript so I hope its not a case of me not knowing what to google.

EDIT: Here's what I have so far (FIXED the main part of my question)

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
        var progress = ((scroll * 145) / 100);
        var prog = document.getElementById("prog");
        prog.innerHTML = scroll + "px " + progress + "%";

        header = document.getElementById('header');

        if (progress < 5) {
            header.style.height = 145 + "px";
        }
        if (progress > 5 || progress < 100) {
            header.style.height = (145 - progress + (scroll / 2)) + "px";
        }
        if (progress >= 100) {
            header.style.height = 75 + "px";
            header.style.opacity = 0.8;
        }
    });

    function getCurrentScroll() {
        return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
});
```

When the middle if statement is true, the user will be between the minimum (0) and maximum scroll points for the header (150).
Why does the first If statement not work as when I scroll up with my trackpad passed the top of the page the header continues to grow?

Comment: Hiya, this is a very broad question... what have you tried? what point did you get stuck on? what have you researched to get it working again? have you got some psuedo code? have you tried asking the people at kreisi.at what they did (or digging into their css/js)?

Comment: Hey, I've been trying quite a few things. Right now I'm trying to make a js function that adjusts the height of the header in relation to the percentage of the header's height has been scrolled down. I am struggling with the maths a bit though as it's pretty late

Comment: I had to scroll pretty slow to notice the initial effect. I'm personally not a huge fan of the shrinking header wave. does that help? lol ;)

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to learn as much as I can here so design preferences are pretty irrelevant

Comment: Add your code to your question for us and we can dissect it and suggest fixes :)

Comment: Will do, I've solved it myself nearly but there are some problems I will ask about. Should be up in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You create 2 different classes. 1 class for the regular header and then a class for the sticky header. Use jQuery for is detecting the scroll position of the window. Usually people use a css3 transition to make the animation but just leave it out for the quick change.

HTML

```
<header>Sticky Header</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 108px;
    height: 108px;
    background: #335C7D;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
header.sticky {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 12px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #efc47D;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lj0oyL4/

You can read a tutorial on this topic over at [webdesignerdepot.](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/)

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer, I'm wanting to make a header like the one in the link where if you were to stop halfway through scrolling, the size change would stop before resuming when you do

Comment: Are you asking for the header to resume original size if the user stopped scrolling and then when they start scrolling again the header gets smaller?

Comment: No, the link in the original question shows what I mean. You have to scroll quite slowly to see it though. It's more than the standard scroll to point and snap on a class

Answer (score 0):

First set your header to fixed and 100%, possibly add z-index.

Then you will need the following CSS

```
.header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    z-index:9999; //only if you need the header on top of everything
}
.header.shorty{
    height:50px;
}
```

Then we can add the shorty call once the page has scrolled.

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
    $(".header").addClass("shorty");
 }else{
     $(".header").removeClass("shorty");
 }
 });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer, I'm wanting to make a header like the one in the link where if you were to stop halfway through scrolling, the size change would stop before resuming when you do

Answer (score 0):

This may not be perfect but it's what I think what you want to do and the way I would do it. Excuse me if this is incorrect.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("#everything").scroll(function() {
    var startAt = 40; //How many pixles scrolled to start effect, 0 would match link
    if ($("#everything").scrollTop() >= startAt) {
      var scroll = $("#everything").scrollTop(),
        total = 0, // go to this value
        distance = 40, //distance to shrink
        value = (scroll < distance) ? total : total + (distance - (scroll - startAt));

      $("#head").css("height", value); //change #head to what ever you want to shrink
    } else {
      $("#head").css("background-color", value);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Disables regular scrolling */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#everything {
  overflow: scroll;
  /* enables content to scroll */
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="everything">
    <div id="head">header</div>
    <span>
Text Following text is so the page can scroll: <br/>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer porta velit eu turpis imperdiet congue. Morbi nec mi ipsum. Nam eu nunc in lorem sagittis feugiat a quis nisl. Donec suscipit leo quis magna egestas, id convallis leo gravida. Curabitur finibus lectus ut metus feugiat, eu tincidunt eros tempor. Fusce facilisis nunc vulputate, posuere velit nec, ultrices diam. Vestibulum aliquam velit in lectus imperdiet, vitae condimentum lectus finibus. Aliquam ac arcu eget velit molestie rhoncus. Etiam rhoncus, tellus nec lacinia porta, diam lorem ultrices sem, et dignissim ipsum augue non augue. Suspendisse tincidunt felis sit amet orci accumsan, at ornare tellus viverra. Nam viverra nulla in urna elementum ornare.Sed interdum nisi libero, id porta turpis consectetur vitae. Curabitur nunc ex, interdum eget hendrerit maximus, faucibus non est. Etiam scelerisque condimentum eleifend. Integer ac ligula eget magna porta tristique at eu neque. Sed venenatis ipsum non metus sodales finibus. Suspendisse nec nunc lobortis ligula venenatis tristique. Suspendisse aliquam leo elit, et pretium ipsum tempor sed. Maecenas tincidunt dictum leo sit amet accumsan. Nullam eu viverra nulla. Aenean vehicula tellus a mauris malesuada interdum. Sed libero lacus, consectetur at condimentum vel, egestas vitae nisl.Mauris facilisis tincidunt magna, at gravida elit. Cras molestie eros sed tincidunt ultricies. Pellentesque eleifend egestas orci, sit amet condimentum nisl semper eleifend. Sed ipsum elit, aliquet nec lacinia a, maximus eu dolor. Quisque finibus efficitur odio gravida convallis. Vivamus nec velit in est ornare luctus at a risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin condimentum eget est non posuere. Vivamus ante quam, bibendum in tincidunt ut, egestas sed mauris. Nunc non interdum nibh, nec ornare tellus. In interdum elit nisi, a interdum est tempor id. Cras a elit ut purus ornare mollis sit amet ut est. Cras ut ex sed neque lacinia accumsan quis aliquet turpis. Quisque nisl nunc, pretium sed lectus pretium, lacinia ornare magna. Curabitur sit amet felis turpis. Morbi nisi mi, mattis quis tempor ut, accumsan nec ex.
      </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```